# What is this instrument that has "PACK" written on it and a temperature scale?

Tags: flight-instruments, feature-identification

All I know right now is that it’s made in 1973. Another instrument I have is from a b727 and is dated 1982. This one I have no clue. Serial number- H 2590. The brand is Amphenol. That’s all the info I can find. I have some pictures.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the [pack temperature gauge for the air conditioning system on the 727](https://www.boeing-727.com/Data/systems/infoaircon.html)

> **To monitor the operation of the air cycle machines, each has a
>   temperature transmitter at the outlet off  its compressor.  The
>   temperature sensed is displayed on a pack temperature gauge for each
>   pack.**  As more air is directed through cycle machine to provide more
>   cooling, more compression is  required from the compressor.  This
>   results in a higher compressor outlet temperature.  Therefore, the
>   pack temperature gauge monitors air cycle machine work load.  To
>   protect the compressor from excessively high temperature an over
>   temperature sensor at the outlet of the compressor will cause the pack
>   to shut down if the temperature reaches the limiting value.  Another
>   temperature limiting sensor located at the inlet to the turbine.

You can find a [full video of how that section of the flight engineer panel works here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OuzraJp26U)

[image]
Here it is on the flight engineer's panel ([airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Orca-Bay-Aviation/Boeing-727-232-Adv/1255032)).